# comunication between Web browser and java

Tags: java, browser, web, communication

I Am developing a private web site in PHP-html / Ajax and a client program in Java.

I have just seen that apple can, by Firefox or other, open iTunes to load content.

I want to do the same or better:

I try to make a program which can “talk” to javascript or just write a lockFile (tempfile) and so get data through this one, i try to get at least a communication Web browser - > java, but i'd rather if possible a bi-directional communication.

So if somebody have any solution, it’s will be great cause I googlised it, i tried local Storage in html5, File access in javascript … nothing really works and I don’t  want the program to ask the server Avery time.

Comment: You can't do that using pure HTML + Javascript for secutiry issues. You have to build an applet and the client should install it in his/her machine to make the file operations you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a number of ways but you must have in mind the [cross-domain restrictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). I've been doing this with sockets.

1 - You need a bridge to comunicate your web with your server this could be done with a java applet or a flash socket bridge so that you can call your server and your javascript client code.

2 - You need url-redirect rule in your server so that when your client makes a request it always makes it in the same domain but gets where your socket server finally is. You client can't go to a different domain but your server can. This is needed to skip the cross-domain restriction.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [JxBrowser](http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser) library that allows embedding Google Chromium engine into Java Swing applications. You can use this library to embed Browser component into your client Java application and load your PHP web page, like iTunes loads App Store.

It provides API for two-way communication Java-to-JavaScript-to-Java: http://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/docs/JxBrowser-PGuide.html#javascript-java-bridge

The following code demonstrates how to embed Browser component, load URL, invoke JavaScript code on the loaded web page and register Java function on JavaScript side that will be invoked every time when JavaScript invokes it:

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserFactory;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserFunction;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.JSValue;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.events.FinishLoadingEvent;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.events.LoadAdapter;

/**
 * The sample demonstrates how to register a new JavaScript function and
 * map it to a Java method that will be invoked every time when the JavaScript
 * function is invoked.
 */
public class JavaScriptJavaSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Browser browser = BrowserFactory.create();
        // Register "MyFunction" JavaScript function and associate Java callback with it
        browser.registerFunction("MyFunction", new BrowserFunction() {
            public JSValue invoke(JSValue... args) {
                for (JSValue arg : args) {
                    System.out.println("arg = " + arg);
                }
                return JSValue.create("Hello!");
            }
        });

        // Create JFrame and embed Browser component to display web pages
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(browser.getView().getComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Register Load listener to get notification when web page is loaded completely
        browser.addLoadListener(new LoadAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onFinishLoadingFrame(FinishLoadingEvent event) {
                if (event.isMainFrame()) {
                    Browser browser = event.getBrowser();
                    // Invoke our registered JavaScript function
                    JSValue returnValue = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue(
                            "MyFunction('Hello JxBrowser!', 1, 2, 3, true);");
                    System.out.println("return value = " + returnValue);
                }
            }
        });
        browser.loadURL("about:blank");
    }
}
```